# Type your info without having to click the form

Tags: javascript, python

I'm wondering if there's an easy way (using python/js/html) to automatically select the form to insert credentials.

Basically at the login-page you don't have to click the 'username' form and can type right away.

Thanks!

Comment: `$("#inputID").focus()` if jQuery is allowed. See https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: You can use the jquery library to pick username input field and add focus to it once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Using JavaScript you can do [HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus):

```js
document.getElementById('input').focus();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Answer (score 4):

simply use 'autofocus' in input html `<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus>`